# Unity multiple update functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

I am a beginner with Unity.Can I have multiple updates methods in one script?After i instantiate a bullet , I would like it to get a script which will destroy it after 5 seconds or when it hits something.So i'll do something like this:

```
public class mainclass : Monobehaviour
{
      private class destroy_bullet
        {
         void start()
         {
         this.gameObject.addComponent<mycollider>();
          Destroy(this.gameObject , 5);
         }
       void onCollisionEnter2D()
        {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }



void update()
{
 if (mouse is pressed)
{
 GameObject bullet = Instantiate(...);
 bullet.addComponent<destroy_bullet>();
 }
}
}
```

I would prefer doing that instead of creating a new script , and attaching it to my prefab from unity.Would this be possible?If not , why?I really like OOP so I'd love to understand it better!

Comment: on the start function you could save the time you created the object while on the updated function you could check the current time, and if it great that 5 seconds to destroy the object, you cannot have 2 update functions, and it would not be useful.

Comment: @AndriNic mainclass is attached to enemy , not to its bullets.So instead of creating a new script to destroy the bullets i d like to do it here

Comment: Yes you can .. **but** it makes no sense ^^ In order to have the message methods like (`Start`, `Update`, etc) be called from the Unity framework they need to be in a `MonoBehaviour` class. And the editor makes sure that one of these is only usable if a) it is the only one in a file b) the file name matches the class name and c) it is not nested under another class ... So you can have as many subclasses with whatever methods you want in your MonoBehaviour class ... but non of theire methods are automatically called if that is what you are hoping for ...

Comment: And then further note that the message methods are cases sensitive and need to be exactly as the engine expects them  .. it is `Start`, `Update`, `OnCollisionEnter2D` .. not `start`, `update`, `oncollisionenter2d` ... And it is also `AddComponent` not `addComponent` .. and well as said your type `destroy_bullet` is no component .. so it can't be added as one

Comment: Can you explain Why you think this is like "OOP" ?

Comment: The method you describe that you prefer not to do? That's how you should do it. Create a script for the bullet and attach it to the prefab. Then all the bullets will automatically have that script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can destroy an object after a given amount of time or when colliding in unity by using the `Destroy(Gameobject, Time)` function as well as a collision detection function. I would recommend that you rewrite your Destroy code on lines 3-13 to destroy an object and check for collisions in a similar way to this this:

```
void Awake() //Awake runs when a MonoBehaviour is instantiated
{
  Destroy(this.gameobject, 5f); //This will destroy the game-object after 5 seconds
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D() //OnCollisionEnter is called when the object enters the bounds of another collider
{
  Destroy(this.gameobject); //This will destroy the game-object when it enters a collider
}
```

Remember that you can always check the unity scripting API at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/.

- Documentation on the `Destroy` method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html
- Documentation on the `OnCollisionEnter2D` function: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html